# Create new Environment config sails.js

Tags: sails.js

There are 2 to Environments config on `/config/env/`

`development.js` and `production.js`

You can run production config with: `sails lift --prod`

development runs by default: `sails lift`

how to create staging environment config like `/config/env/staging.js`
and run with: `sails lift --staging`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `--prod` argument is built-in to the Sails CLI; there's no mechanism for adding new arguments to that currently.  But you can get the same effect using the `NODE_ENV` environment variable:

linux & mac:

```
export NODE_ENV=staging sails lift
```

windows:

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 4):

It is extremely easy in sails 0.11. Now you can just add subfolder to you `config/env` directory and sails engine will interpret it as new environment.

In your case you just need to create folder `config/env/staging`, put there all needed configuration files and start your application with

```
NODE_ENV=staging sails lift
```

Migration guide for sails 0.11 you [can find in documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/changelog/0.11).